# metapost " missing `,' has been inserted." compilation error

Tags: errors, metapost, metafun

I'm quite new to this language and can't figure out the error in following code. Any help would be appreciated !

```
verbatimtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
etex;

beginfig(1)

u := 10mm;
v := 0.8u;

for i=1 upto 5:
    pickup pensquare scaled 0.6pt;
    draw (-v*i,-0.1u)..(-v*i,0.1u)
        withcolor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    draw (v*i,-0.1u)..(v*i,0.1u)
        withcolor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);


    label.bot(textext("$" & (decimal (-v*i)) & "$"), (-v*i, -0.2u))
        withcolor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    label.bot(textext("$" & (decimal (v*i)) & "$"), (v*i, -0.2u))
        withcolor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
endfor;
endfig;

end
```

gives following error:

```
! Missing `,' has been inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   (
<for(1)> ...hcolor(0.5,0.5,0.5);label.bot(textext(
                                                  "$"&(decimal(-v*(EXPR0)))&...
l.59     endfor
               ;
```

Comment: Where is `textext` defined?

Comment: `textext` is a MetaFun macro, so you have to process the file with `mpost '&metafun' test.mp`.  Unfortunately, the output will only contain “unknown”.  I asked on the mailing list why this is happening: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/093806.html

Comment: @AndrewSwann I think it is part of `metafun`, which is part of `ConTeXt`.

Comment: It is also in `latexmp`, perhaps that has not been loaded.

Comment: How are you compiling the document?

Comment: @Aditya from terminal `mptopdf file.mp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The error

The "some reason" is that in your MWE (as given) the `textext` macro is not defined, so MetaPost reads "textext" as a variable name token instead, in the hope that it will be able to expand it into an appropriate parameter for the `label` macro.  When the tokenizer gets to the `(` token, it can't add this to the variable name token that it's just read in any legal way, so it assigns the token to the first parameter for `label` and moves on to look for the next parameter.  But `label` is defined (in `plain.mp`) with a comma token to separate the parameters, so the next thing in the input should be a `,` but it in fact is is a `(`.  At this point the tokenizer admits defeat and throws the error that you see.

### What can you do about it?

1. As you have already discovered you can abandon `textext` altogether and just get a plain label.  But that's a bit disappointing because it means the negative numbers in your loop get hyphens instead of mathematical minus signs (see the hack below for a quick way round this).
2. As suggested in the comments, you can call `mpost` with the `&metafun` option so that it loads all the useful macros written for Context, including `textext()`.
3. You can put "input TEX" at the top of your program, and then replace your calls to `textext()` with calls to `TEX()` -- this works with plain `mpost`
4. You can wrap your code up in an `mplib` shell like this, with the immensely useful `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` option and compile with `lualatex`:

   ```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
   \usepackage{luatex85}
   \usepackage{luamplib}
   \usepackage{mathptmx}
   \begin{document}
   \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
   \begin{mplibcode}
   beginfig(1);
   u := 10mm; v := 0.8u;
   drawoptions(withcolor 1/2 white);
   for i=-5 upto 5:
       if i <> 0:
           draw (v*i, -1/10 u) .. (v*i, 1/10 u);
           label.bot("$" & decimal i & "$", (v*i, -1/5 u));
       fi
   endfor;
   draw (left--right) scaled 5.5v;
   drawoptions();
   endfig;
   \end{mplibcode}
   \end{document}
   ```

   (I made a couple of trivial tidy-ups...).  Notice that this has the (great) advantage that you don't need a `verbatimtex` block.  You just put your normal latex preamble in, to get: [image]

You may be able to guess by now that I would recommend option 4.

### The promised hack

If you want to stick with plain MP, but you still want typographical minus signs in a loop, then here is a hack.   First you need to choose a default font that is *not* `cmr10`.  If you want Computer Modern then do

```
defaultfont := "texnansi-lmr10";  % for Computer Modern Roman
```

if you want Times (as in the OP) then do

```
defaultfont := "ptmr8r";
```

then you can try the following:

```
string minus_sign;
minus_sign := char 143; % if you are using the texnansi encoding
minus_sign := char 12;  % if you are using the 8r encoding
for x=-10 upto 10: 
   label(if x<0: minus_sign & fi decimal abs(x), (x*u,-5)); 
endfor
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar in spirit to Thruston's answer, but uses ConTeXt (rather than LaTeX). ConTeXt can directly compile Metapost files using

```
context filename.mp
```

provided you don't have any latexism in your code. This is roughly equivalent to compiling a ConTeXt document

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
....
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

So, if you want to change fonts etc., you can set a ConTeXt environment with all the relevant setups, and then run

```
context --environment=<name-of-environment-file> <name-of-mp-file>
```

Comment: I was thinking about this as well (of course) but keep in mind that OP is using the `mathptmx` package.  I don't know whether there is an equivalent in ConTeXt.

Comment: Isn't `\setupbodyfont[pagella]` functionally equivalent?

Comment: It's more similar to TeX Gyre Termes but not quite the same and only applies to math mode.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `textext` caused the problem.

Following simple label worked well inside for cycle.

```
label.bot(decimal (-0.8*i), (-v*i, -0.2u))
    withcolor(0.3,0.3,0.3);
```